# Swift recursive protocol: How to mark leave node?

Tags: swift, recursion, macos-sierra, swift-protocols

I've a tree of (different) `structs` which I want to show in an `NSOutlineView`. I've also written an update function which determines the move/insert/reload operations on the outline view.

To make the update function more generic, I've written a protocol that makes the different structs similar:

```
protocol Outlinable: Equatable, Identifiable {
    associatedtype T: Outlinable

    var children: [T]? { get }
}
```

The `children` array is an optional to mark that a node might not have children.
I've made two structs conform to this protocol:

```
struct ImageWithErrors: Decodable, FetchableRecord {
    let imageFile: ImageFile
    let imageFileErrors: [ImageFileError]
}

struct LayerImagesListItem: Decodable, FetchableRecord {
    let layer: Layer
    let imageFiles: [ImageWithErrors]
}

extension LayerImagesListItem: Identifiable, Outlinable {
    var id: Int64 { get { layer.id! }}
    var children: [ImageWithErrors]? { get { imageFiles }}
}

extension ImageWithErrors: Identifiable, Outlinable {
    var id: Int64 { get { -imageFile.id! }}
    var children: [Outlinable]? { get { return nil }}
}
```

The `LayerImagesListItem` is a root struct, while the `ImageWithErrors` is (currently) a leave struct. But on this last struct I get the errors:

```
Type 'ImageWithErrors' does not conform to protocol 'Outlinable'
Protocol 'Outlinable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

I've tried replacing `[Outlinable]` with `[Any]` but that doesn't solve anything.

How can I tell Swift that `ImageWithErrors` is never going to return any `children`?

Comment: Could you show the definition of `LayerImagesListItem` & `ImageWithErrors`, and how they conform to `Outlinable` with the setting of `associatedtype` (especially)?

Comment: In the extension `children` cannot be declared as the protocol type. Due to the associated type it must be a concrete type. Isn't the type supposed to be `[ImageWithErrors]?`

Comment: I would try to solve this by using the Composite design pattern instead. Also, is Equatable and Identifiable really part of the use case for this protocol or are you trying to solve many things with one solution?

Comment: @vadian No and Yes,  `ImageWithErrors` doesn't have any children, so the type shouldn't really be `ImageWithErrors`, but using this as type (and always returning nil) does allow me to compile!
@JoakimDanielson The update function I wrote needs the structs to also be `Identifiable` and `Equatable`, so I though it proper to declare that requirement in this way. Composition is difficult here as I get the tree from elsewhere

Comment: Would't it be easier to use **one** type with computed properties `isRoot` and `isLeaf`?

Comment: I hoped the one type could be a protocol to which I can make them all conform :). It would have the advantage that I don't need to copy the structure into the new type each time it changes externally, or convert back to the original type if I change some data from the outline view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ImageWithErrors` can *never* have children, you could use [`Never`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/never).

```swift
extension Never: Outlinable {
    var children: [Never]? { nil }
}

extension ImageWithErrors: Identifiable, Outlinable {
    var id: Int64 { get { -imageFile.id! }}
    var children: [Never]? { get { return nil }}
}

if let children = ImageWithErrors(imageFile: .init(), imageFileErrors: []).children {
    for child in children {
        print("there will never be any \(child)")
    }
} else {
    print("children is always nil")
}
```

It is meant to be used:

> as the return type when declaring a closure, function, or method that unconditionally throws an error, traps, or otherwise does not terminate.

but since `ImageWithErrors.children` is of type `[Never]` and always return `nil` that should not be an issue.

Comment: I tried this, but it seems to only work for macOS 12 or newer. I've to target 10.15, so I'm out of luck here I'm afraid.

Comment: weird! `Never` is supposed to be available from macOS 10.10+. Out of curiosity, do you remember the error message?

Comment: Something about `Never` conforming to `Outlinable` being only possible from 12+

Comment: Ohh thanks for the information! I'm just thinking maybe you can create your "own" `Never`. Like, just an empty struct to act like a leaf marker ?

Comment: Yes, I went for something similar. I’ll mark your answer as accepted as its the best solution, especially for newer OS versions.